# HAML is missing link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I am learning Haml and for one of my projects I am getting an error

> NoMethodError at / undefined method `link_to' for # Ruby    (**TEMPLATE**): in block (2 levels) in
>   singletonclass, line 14 Web   GET 0.0.0.0/

I had simply git cloned that project from  https://github.com/crofty/Simple-Site.git

and added a link_to   (to test out)  into index.haml

```
  %div.container{class: class_name}
    = link_to 'x' 'y'
```

On my linux vm another project is using haml and from within there the link_to statements work.

I initialy though that haml some how allows to include/exclude certain Ruby libraries (like actionpack ), and that for this Simple-Site I had to inculde something extra, but this doesnot seem to be the case and HAML when installed via gem install haml , should be allowing = link_to and similar calls by default.

WOuld apperciate on pointers where I have to look to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`link_to` is a Rails helper (from [ActionView](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)). The given project is not a Rails project, so those helpers are not available in templates (Haml or otherwise).

Comment: but I have another project (generated by this middleman template):  https://github.com/nathos/amicus and link_to works within HAML file

Comment: `link_to` is also provided by Middleman (via Padrino, an alternative to Rails). See http://middlemanapp.com/basics/helpers/#toc_1 for docs. Same method, but from different libraries.

Comment: Incredible. Being a noob, I thought middleman only abstracts out existing lower level tools